# How to add text in a specific cell of table

Tags: html

I made a 5x5 table and a textarea, for example, I write an "X" in the area choose which row and column I want to add in, and the program adds it. I want to create a tictactoe game (this is my task) with database, I already made the database which points are already used, I just need this part of the program.

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%" style="height:10%" id="table1">
            <tr id="vmi">
                <td class="cella" id="tr0td1"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr0td2"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr0td3"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr0td4"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr0td5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cella" id="tr1td1"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr1td2"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr1td3"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr1td4"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr1td5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cella" id="tr2td1"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr2td2"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr2td3"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr2td4"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr2td5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cella" id="tr3td1"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr3td2"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr3td3"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr3td4"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr3td5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cella" id="tr4td1"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr4td2"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr4td3"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr4td4"></td>
                <td class="cella" id="tr4td5"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form name="tictactoe" action="tictactoe.php" method="POST">
            Character(X or O):
            <input type="text" id='character' name='Character' class='editor'>
            <label for='tr'>Row: <input id='sor' type='number' min='0' name='Sor'> 
            <label for='td'>Column: <input id='column'type='number' name='Column' max='5'>
            <button id='Add!'>Add!</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: why do you need PHP here? to save current game State?

Comment: I need to save already used points, it's just, my teacher asked me to do it

Comment: you need a JavaScript to add X and O is table ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to add X and O in the table, I thought it's easy or at least easier to use JS for this purpose

Comment: Using POST like this will cause tictactoe.php to be loaded. That is to say, your page will dissapear and the output of the php will appear. The php can draw the correct entries into the table. The other way to do it would be to send the requested action using AJAX. It's also oworth pointing out that it seems odd to use 0 for the first row and 1 for the first column. Also, the min/max attributes for the inputs seem to need a little more attention. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
       table {border: 1px solid black;}
       td {border: 1px solid black;height: 10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%" style="height:10%" id="table1">
<tr id="vmi">
<td class="cella" id="tr0td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
Character(X or O):
<input type="text" id='character' name='Character' class='editor'>
<label for='tr'>Row: <input id='sor' type='number' min='0' name='Sor'> 
<label for='td'>Column: <input id='column'type='number' name='Column' max='5'>
<button type='button' onclick="addXO()">submit</button> 
</form>

<script>
function addXO() {
    var row = document.getElementById('sor').value;
    var column = document.getElementById('column').value;
    var character = document.getElementById('character').value;

    document.getElementById('tr'+row+'td'+column).innerHTML  = character;

    // here you can do API call using XHR to store values in database

    return false;
}
</script>
```